# What's the difference between chat and channel in telegram?

Tags: telethon

What's the difference between chat and channel in telegram?

When a user creates a new conversation in telegram, and maybe change it to a public group, will the type be changed?

by calling `client.get_input_entity(url)`

A peer to peer chat in telethon is a what type, Channel or Chat?

A private chat group in telethon is a what type, Channel or Chat?

A mega group in telethon is a what type, Channel or Chat?

Answer (score 2):

chats are in four type:

- private chat (between two user)
- group chat (normal groups)
- supper groups
- channel

when you get a message from telegram with telethon you have three flag:

- is_private
- is_group
- is_channel

meaning of flags:

- if is_private = 1 , is_group = 0 , is_channel = 0 chat is private chat
- if is_private = 0 , is_group = 1 , is_channel = 0 chat is normal group
- if is_private = 0 , is_group = 1 , is_channel = 1 chat is supper group
- if is_private = 0 , is_group = 0 , is_channel = 1 chat is channel

Answer (score 1):

the id of chat change depending of is an user or chat. If is user chat id be for example: 1233563 and if chat is in group, id chat be like: -233412312. The group chat id is negative